# Thai and English in a postgresql

Tags: postgresql, collation, encoding

I have a postgresql DB with Thai and English values/strings in several tables.

Currently I have the following settings

```
| Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype |
| UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8  |
```

If I order by a column with Thai values, the sort order is not correct.

What settings should I change to have postgresql sort correctly?

Comment: In future you really need to provide: Your PostgreSQL version (`SELECT version()`) and an example showing what's happening, e.g. a create table, a couple of inserts, a select, the results you get, and the results you think you *should* get.

Answer (score 1):

On PostgreSQL 9.1 and newer, you can use the `COLLATE` qualifier on an operation to override the database's default collation. See [the manual for information on collation support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html).

E.g.

```
SELECT a, b FROM mytable ORDER BY c COLLATE 'th_TH.UTF-8';
```

Note that PostgreSQL can't mix different collations, using a dynamic collation based on detected language. It doesn't work like that.

On prior versions you must use a single database-wide collation. So you'd have to dump your database, `CREATE DATABASE ... ENCODING 'UTF-8' LC_COLLATE 'th_TH.UTF-8'`, and re-load.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Decided on a different tack, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since the DB has both Engliah and Thai I decided to change the collation for the columns.

```
ALTER TABLE books ALTER thai_title TYPE varchar(255) COLLATE "C";
```